# Notification Builder action not working on API 31 (Android 12)

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm stuck while dealing with this api 31. i made a chat app. When I create an action button to receive a phone call it works on android below API 31 or below Android 12, but it doesn't work on Android 12 (only work if the notification is not has action). maybe someone here can help me in finding a solution to this problem?

FirebaseService.java

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    boolean cancelNotification = false;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(params);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
    }
    else {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    }

    String channel_id = getNotificationData(data, "channel");

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getNotificationData(data, "title"))
            .setContentText(getNotificationData(data, "body"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if(channel_id.equals("cll2") && getNotificationData(data, "call_action").equals("open")){
        playCallSound(this);

        if(WindowUtil.isAppOnBackground(this) || isScreenOff()){
            ArrayList<String> par = new ArrayList<>();

            par.add("call_channel");
            par.add("call_type");
            par.add("call_token");
            par.add("call_peer");

            String callType = getNotificationData(data, "call_type");

            if(callType.equals("3") || callType.equals("4")){
                par.add("call_group_name");
                par.add("call_group_caller");
            }

            Intent receiveCallAction = new Intent(this, CallReceiver.class);
            receiveCallAction.putExtra("action", "ANSWER");

            Intent cancelCallAction = new Intent(this, CallReceiver.class);
            cancelCallAction.putExtra("action", "DECLINE");

            for (String s : par) {
                receiveCallAction.putExtra(s, getNotificationData(data, s));
                cancelCallAction.putExtra(s, getNotificationData(data, s));
            }

            notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);

            receiveCallAction.setAction("RECEIVE_CALL");
            cancelCallAction.setAction("CANCEL_CALL");

            PendingIntent receiveCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1200, receiveCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            PendingIntent cancelCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1201, cancelCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            notificationBuilder
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_call_24_green, "Answer", receiveCallPendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_call_red_24, "Decline", cancelCallPendingIntent);
        }else{
            cancelNotification = true;
        }
    }if(channel_id.equals("cll2") && getNotificationData(data, "call_action").equals("end_timeout")){
        stopRinging();
    }else if(channel_id.equals("ntf1")){
        if(UserUtil.IS_CHAT_ACTIVITY){
            cancelNotification = true;
        }

        if(!cancelNotification){
            playNotificationSound(this);
        }
    }

    if(!cancelNotification){
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channel_id,
                    getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

CallReceiver.java (Broadcast Receiver)

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
        String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");

        // Perform the action
        performClickAction(context, action, intent.getExtras());

        // Close the notification after the click action is performed.
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(1000);

        // Stop the ringtone
        stopRinging();
    }
}
```

on my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".services.FirebaseService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.CallReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="CALL_RECEIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Thank you

Comment: Try to use this flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`

Comment: Hello!,  thankyou for your response, in my case, normal notification (without action) is showing but if the notfication has a action, this is not working @Zain

Comment: Yeah I see, could you try this `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` in the boradcast PendingIntent `receiveCallPendingIntent` & `cancelCallPendingIntent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this problem by this code

```
 PendingIntent receiveCallPendingIntent;
        PendingIntent cancelCallPendingIntent;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            receiveCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1200, receiveCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            cancelCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1201, cancelCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }else{
            receiveCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1200, receiveCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            cancelCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1201, cancelCallAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```

also add this permission for force Android 12^ (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /><receiver
        android:name=".receiver.CallReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```